# ImageIO.read(inputstream) gives null in BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-scaling

I am trying to resize image and for that first i am turning my inputstream to buffered image and then using that bufferedimage to scale it

```
BufferedImage bim=null;
try {
     bim=ImageIO.read(myinputstream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

    Image img=bim.getScaledInstance(100, 100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

but the line :

```
bim=ImageIO.read(myinputstream);
```

doesn't give any exception and just returns null in bim . Why can't imageIO read my inputstream. I used this stream to write it on an image and it worked fine but when ImageIO reads it , it returns null . I read somewhere that i need to pass in file object but why is there even an option then. Can someone help me .

Comment: The data in the input stream isn't a recognized image format.

Comment: i m sending a png image sir

Comment: Clearly not. You are sending it how? Have you considered the possibility of bugs in the sending code?

Comment: i m sending it using postman . I have used the same inputstream to write it on my file and that worked perfectly . What could be wrong

Answer (score -2):

See [ImageIO.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream-).

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the stream, null is returned.

I suspect you have that problem. Look at how you are registering your `ImageReader`s?

Comment: i read that but sorry i didn't understand , How do i solve this? :/

Comment: so i need to pass in an imageinputstream instead of an inputstream?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan - I'd say no - the `InputStream` form wraps the stream in an `ImageInputStream`. I'd suggest you investigate the readers using [getImageReadersByFormatName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageReadersByFormatName-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(myimageinputstream);
        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        }      

it always enters the if , what does it mean then? :/

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOann - That means there are no `ImageReader`s registered. There are a number of examples [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.imageio.ImageReader) that may help. A google searchj for "*ImageReader imageio java register*" shows more examples.

Comment: i read the second example on the link u gave me a while ago , i coudn't understand the format parameter . Is that should i pass , jpg or png etc in it?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan - Not sure - what type of image is it? Pick the extension to match.